# How can I plot a linear and quadratic predictors from a regression model, while also controlling for other variables?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, polynomial

Here is some data and a model. It consists of a linear and quadratic predictor (a and a2) and a linear control variable (b).

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

d <- as.data.table(cbind(a = rnorm(50), b = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50)))
d$a2 <- (d$a)^2

m <- lm(y ~ a + a2 + b, data = d)
```

I would like to plot the linear and quadratic effects, while also controlling for b.

I have found how to do this if I want only the effects of a and a2:

```
ggplot(d,
       aes(x = a, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x,
              aes(color = "linear"),
              se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x + I(x^2),
              aes(color = "quadratic"),
              se = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

But how can I plot this while also controlling for b?

Comment: What is "controlling for b" in your mind? A pure coding question is off-topic here and should be posted to Stack Overflow, but I do think there's some statistics to discuss.

Comment: I tried posting there and was told to come here! Essentially I want to plot a and a2 as they exist in model m; that is, controlling for b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write your model as

$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\beta_2x_i^2+\beta_3z_i$

where I have renamed a to $x$ and b to $z$. If you are interested in plotting the marginal effects, i.e. $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_i}$, that is straight forward. Because your specification is quadratic in $x$, the marginal effect is not constant:

$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_i} = \beta_1+\beta_2x_i.$

You can simply create a plot with $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_i}$ on the vertical axis and $x$ on the horizontal axis.

```
m <- lm(y ~ a + a2 + b, data = d)
marginal_effect <- m$coefficients[1]+m$coefficients[2]*a
plot(a,marginal_effect)
```

The problem with what I think you are asking is as follows: If you are interested in plotting the fitted values of $y$ against the observed values $x$ while controlling for $z$, you would have a different plot any given value of $z$ (what you called b). Notice the fitted value of $y_i$ is as follows:

$\hat{y_i} = \hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_i+\hat{\beta_2}x_i^2+\hat{\beta_3}z_i$

Suppose we fix $z_i$ at $z_i=4$. Then we have:

$\hat{y_i} = \hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_i+\hat{\beta_2}x_i^2+4\hat{\beta_3}$

so we can create a plot of $x$ vs. $y$ while controlling for $z$. However, if we change the value of $z$, the plot changes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I think that I must be making a mistake in the way I'm wording the question. If I take out the quadratic effect for a moment–isn't it a common thing to plot: the effect of x when controlling for z? That is, the effect of x in: y ~ x + z. Does something become more complicated when the predictor of interest is a quadratic term?

Comment: If you remove the quadratic term, the logic is still the same: there is a different plot of predicted $y$ and $x$ for every different value of $z$.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now. I suppose what I am after, then, is a plot of the marginal effect of x^2, keeping z constant at whatever value it is fixed at in the regression. Would that be z = 0? Edit: Sorry, it would be fixing z at its mean?

Comment: You would not plot the marginal effect of $x^2$, but of $x$. If you have the quadratic specification, the marginal effect is a straight line $\hat{\beta_1}+\hat{\beta_1}x$. If you remove the quadratic term, a plot doesn't tell you anything useful, because the marginal effect is constant, the plot would be a horizontal line.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept. If you have more questions, I am happy to elaborate.

Comment: Happy to accept because it was a great answer. However I'm still not clear on your last point and would love a bit of clarification. To be sure we're on the same page, my thinking would be to have the model: y = x + x^2 + z. And to plot the marginal effect of X^2 after fixing x and z at their means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106964/discussion-between-dave-and-dlnb).